# How does Reentrancy Attack is avoided this case?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain

```
mapping (address => uint) private userBalances;

function withdrawBalance() public {
    uint amountToWithdraw = userBalances[msg.sender];
    userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call.value(amountToWithdraw)(""); // The user's 
balance is already 0, so future invocations won't withdraw anything
    require(success);
}
```

I understand that the reentrancy attack is not able here since we make the '*userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;*' before the call, the attacker cannot repeat the attack indefinitely.

There are 2 problems that I face with this example.

1. What I cannot understand is how this code is functional since we set '*userBalances[msg. sender] = 0;*' before the call, which means that when the next line is executed, the user always withdraws zero amount. What am I missing here?
2. How is possible for an attacker to call the function *'.call'* multiple times in this specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see.

1. When you assign an integer in Solidity, it copies the value. So regardless of what happens to the origin of the value for `amountToWithdraw`, the value of `amountToWithdraw` remains the original value. Therefore it doesn't get set to zero.
2. Re-entrancy attacks typically happen with Ether fallback functions. So the receiver of the Ether transfer is a contract which calls your example contract again upon receiving Ether. Because `msg.sender` is used as the target, therefore that address is a contract which A) has a fallback function which triggers on Ether transfers and B) calls the function withdrawBalance (both in the callback and once somewhere else to trigger the re-entrancy attack)

I'm not exactly sure if this answers your questions, but please specify if some part is still unclear.

Comment: Totally understood. One more question on that, As a preventative technique for reentrancy attacks which one is better:  checks-effects-interactions pattern or mutex state variable? Thanks

Comment: mutex costs gas and makes the code harder to understand. Using checks-effects-interactions doesn't cost anything and makes the code easier to understand, so I'd go for that any day.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable help @Lauri